# Characteristic polynomial and adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The characteristic polynomial of a certain $3\times3$ matrix $A$ is
$p(x) = x^3 − 7x^2 + 5x − 9$. Use this fact to express adj(A) as a linear combination of A^2, A and I.
I think I should Hamilton theorem but I don't how to start can someone help me and do 2 or 3 calculations?

Comment: Note that the “adjoint” is more typically called the [adjugate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Rearrange the equation $p(A)=0$ to find
$$
A(A^2 - 7A + 5I) = 9I
$$